# ConEmu - clickable paths like URLs

Tags: conemu

Conemu lets me set the "highlight and goto" setting to open URLs by control-clicking them. Is it possible make it do something similar for paths? For example, being able to click on a path and open it in explorer

Comment: files is not highlighted if not in current directory. https://conemu.github.io/en/FileLineDetector.html

Comment: it's not correct. any file may be highlighted. https://i.imgur.com/2l9ZVFW.png

Comment: https://conemu.github.io/en/ShellWorkDir.html